# Should we put units of measurements in attribute names?

Tags: naming-conventions

I think most of us agree that **it's a good idea to use a descriptive name for variables**, object attributes, and database columns. If you want to store something's name, you may as well call the attribute `Name` so people know what to put in it.

Where the unit of measurement isn't immediately apparent, I think you should go a step further and include the unit of measurement in the name. `Length_mm`, for example, should help remind developers that they'd better convert the length to mm if the user just entered it in inches.

My database administrator, however, just told me that **including units of measurement in database column names is “frowned upon”**. I think that's just *nuts*, but perhaps there's some risk DBAs know about that I don't.

Throw me a line, here: **should we embed units of measurement in our attribute names?** Why? Why not?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you have a consistent UOM for things, then your DBA's policy is OK.

For example, if timespans are ALWAYS in minutes, etc.

If the UOM could change, then you should store it in another column, alongside the qty.

That said, I tend to side with you on this. **Clarity trumps most things, including this.** I'd rather see `DurationMinutes` than `Duration` and have to guess what the UOM is.

Comment: If the unit is stored alongside the quantity in the DB, this means repetitive sending of the unit + quantity between the DB and a consumer. The alternative is to use a single unit of measurement and *display* in different units by using a calculation. which can simplify things at programming level. Then, adding unit type to the column name means anyone without direct DB access, or who accesses only the quantity, has visibility of the intended units when requesting data. This clarity is important in programming. What is the DBA's justification for *omitting* the units? *Why* is that policy OK?

Answer (score 12):

Yes. You should.

The key, as @[Charles Bretana] pointed out, is legibility and that the other users of your table or developers following you know what you're using.

I would absolutely involve the units/measurement in a field name - in my business you can't guess what you'll find from the context or name: a field entitled MarketValue - is that in millions, thousands or units? US Dollars, Euros, pounds, $CURRENCY? Is that value a percentage, a ratio? Absolute or relative? Daily, monthly, calendar year, financial year? That timestamp, what time zone is it?

Your first, last and only task when providing data is to ensure that it isn't used incorrectly because the consumer wasn't able to find out enough about it. As developers, throwing "Metre", "USD", "GMT", "Percent" or whatever into a field name isn't the least bit smelly.

There are enormous smells that need resolving before the tiny whiff of field naming needs standardising.

Answer (score 7):

This is why the [Mars Climate Orbiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter) crashed into the surface at 350 meters/sec when it was planned to only handle 350 ft/sec (or something like that).

Although "Never say 'Never' or 'Always'" is, in general, a good rule of thumb, here I will bend my rule and say I think you should "always" make it clear what units a numeric value is in.

Comment: See here for the details - https://www.quora.com/Was-NASA-s-Mars-Climate-Orbiter-lost-because-engineering-teams-used-different-measuring-units

Answer (score 6):

The convention of naming all my columns in the format:

```
{name}_in_{unit}
```

helped for one project, since I was using [si units](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/) it actually ended up allowing me to be able to infer the column data type and generally simplify my writing style.

```
length_in_m
speed_in_ms-1
color_in_nm
```

there were a few exceptions that I handled either with *at_time or number_of*:

```
started_at_time
updated_at_time
number_of_rotations
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a good idea anywhere since there is always room for ambiguity.

For example, the with high performance timer class we use, I keep having to check if the GetElapsed() method returns seconds or milliseconds or something else.  If it were called GetElapsedMilliseconds() that would save the confusion.

The only downside being if you wanted to change your mind ... but in that case any clients would need to know about the change anyway.

F# has an interesting twist on this allowing measurement units to be specified in the type system. See this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/andrewkennedy/archive/2008/08/20/units-of-measure-in-f-part-one-introducing-units.aspx), and another stackoverflow question discussing [Are units of measurement unique to F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107243/are-units-of-measurement-unique-to-f)

Answer (score 2):

> Where the unit of measurement isn't immediately apparent, I think you should go a step further and include the unit of measurement in the name. Length_mm, for example, should help remind developers that they'd better convert the length to mm if the user just entered it in inches.

You could go even a step further (in your code, not in the database) and have a Length type, which takes care of the measurement unit and of possible conversions. This is the approach of the "Quantity" pattern in Martin Fowler's "Analysis Patterns" book.

Comment: We tried a Unit of Measure table (UoM) containing unit names, with relationships to it per attribute/column with a unit. The database table became a mess. Worse: no programmer would be able to use ANY number without looking at the unit and shifting it if necessary. We scrapped it.

Answer (score 2):

I've done a lot of database work, and I would not frown upon that at all, nor have I heard of frowning on it.

It's better than the extended properties, which is not apparent to the casual developer.  It's better than in a separate document, because many developers won't read them, and certainly not in great detail.  If the units are set, then having it in the name sounds like a good idea.  If that changes, then when the unit field is added, change the name of the measurement field.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want units of measurement *somewhere*.  I don't know if the column names are a good place or if the schema is better.  Ask your database administrator

- Where is the information about units of measure stored?
- How can I get access to the units programmatically?

If the answers are "it isn't" or "you can't", complain bitterly---they have no right to deny you your naming convention.  Otherwise, all may be happier if you work within the system.

P.S. I really like the support for units of measure that they've put into F#.

Answer (score 1):

For Python datetimes, consider using objects from the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) package. Doing so will capture the unit implicity to microsecond resolution. There is then no basis for including the unit in the variable name.

If you must use an `int` or `float` instead, it is strongly recommend to suffix the unit name abbreviation to the variable name. For example, instead of the variable name `diff`, use `diff_secs` for seconds, `diff_ms` for milliseconds, `diff_µs` for microseconds, or `diff_ns` for nanoseconds.

Answer (score 0):

We don't put units of measurement in column names in our database.  We do, however, have a data dictionary document where all of the columns and relationships are described.

Answer (score 0):

Do not put column datatype in your database column names.

Many Databases have the ability to document/comment columns in some way (in SQL Server it is sp_addextendedproperty), I would suggest that is a more appropriate place.

Comment: That won't allow a programmer to clearly see the required units. You're assuming that there is access to the database.

Comment: I will amend my statement (14 years later) to: Do not put (or column type) in your database column names.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal approach is, if possible, to use a type that leaves no ambiguity as to the measurement. For example in .NET rather than saying `int periodInSeconds` you'd be much better off using `TimeSpan period`.

The F# language actually has units of measurement as part of the type system so you can declare types in units such as `10<m/s>` and `5<s>` and even perform calculations on them so something like `10<m/s> * 5<s>` would result in `50<m>`. [See here for more info](http://blogs.msdn.com/andrewkennedy/archive/2008/08/20/units-of-measure-in-f-part-one-introducing-units.aspx).

So I'd say if possible use a type that conveys your intention, but if that isn't possible then you should probably encode the measurement into the name. It's better and more obvious than a comment.

Answer (score -2):

I have to say, I hate "descriptive" variable names becoming "incredibly verbose" variable names.

My preferred alternative is to use nothing but the unit-of-measure names in short functions. Eg.

```
function velocity(m, s) {
   return m/s;
}
```

You don't need to say "length_m" because in this context, it's obvious that only lengths are measurable in metres.

Having said that. If I was writing a system where units of measure errors were really dangerous, I'd probably use the type system and define a Length class which always converted itself into a standard unit for any calculation. Maybe even different sub-classes for Feet, Metres etc.

Answer (score -3):

NO, the name of the attribute is seperate from its unit of measurement.

If you call a variable length_mm then you are tied to mm.

what if you use a 32bit int to store length_mm, eventually the length in mm may get larger then 62,000, or whatever the limit is on 32bit ints. You cant switch over to m cause you tied you length variable to length_mm.

Comment: But you can't switch anyway without visiting all the code that looks at the value to be sure they can handle the change.  Changing the name is a good way to get the compiler to find those places for you (in code, doesn't work for a database)

Comment: I get your idea, but this is a bad advice to give. Changing the meaning of a variable is a common way to introduce bugs and confusion.

Comment: It think the point here is that ,if say in the lenght_mm we want to store 5,00,000km that would be 5,00,00,00,00,000 in mm so will be a problem for the field size . If I am correct.

Comment: @RobWalker: If one has a database field is called "length_mm" and one changes it to "length_um" (because the things getting measured got smaller and thus more precision was required), it may be hard to automatically find and correct all references to that field (since "length_mm" fields in other databases may have to remain as they are), but if a program hasn't been updated it's probably better to have it squawk than use incorrect data.

Answer (score -4):

I think putting units in your identifiers is a *huge* design smell. It almost surely means that you chose the wrong language: if units are so important to the project, you'd better be using a language whose type system is capable of representing them.

Comment: Indeed it is better to use a time-specific type, but the question is still relevant when such a type is not used, and that is the point of the question.